# Multiple Forms Single View Django

Tags: django, parameters, django-forms

Here is my scenario: I have multiple select boxes on a page, where a user selects choices from a ModelChoiceField and is re-directed to a view with the selected option(s) passed as a parameter. Something like:

```
class BrowseForm(forms.Form):
    thing = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Thing.objects.all(), empty_label=None, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'this.form.submit();'}))
    stuff = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Stuff.objects.all(), empty_label=None, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'this.form.submit();'}))
```

view:

```
def browse(request):
    thing_list = Thing.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BrowseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            thing = form.cleaned_data['thing']
            stuff = form.cleaned_data['stuff']
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('browse_thing', kwargs={'thing':thing, 'stuff':stuff}))
    else:
        form = BrowseForm()
    return render(request, 'browse.html', {'form':form, 'thing_list':thing_list})
```

This requires that I submit both fields of `BrowseForm`, but I want so that there are two different urls for `thing` and `stuff`, where either `thing` or `stuff` is passed as the parameter, not both. Something like:

```
url(r'^browse/things/(?P<thing>[\w-]+)/$', 'views.browse', name='browse_thing'),
url(r'^browse/stuff/(?P<stuff>[\w-]+)/$', 'views.browse', name='browse_stuff'),
```

Is there a way to do this with one form and one view? Or do I need to write a different form for `thing` and `stuff`, then check to see which one is passed in my view and re-direct to the appropriate url accordingly? How would you do this? Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: The regex for the route is exactly the same, so how would you know that one is a `thing` and the other is `stuff`?  I don't see any way to do this with the same route, you'd have to distinguish the route somehow like `r'browse/thing/(?{<thing>[\w-]+)/$'` and similarly for `stuff`.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. I have updated the post accordingly. But how is it recommended in my view to redirect with the appropriate parameters based on which option is selected in the form? Do I need multiple forms, and route to different urls based on inputted parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it doesn't seem very DRY, this is how I solved the problem:

forms.py:

```
class StuffBrowseForm(forms.Form):
    stuff = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Stuff.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'this.form.submit();'}))

class ThingBrowseForm(forms.Form):
    thing = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Thing.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'this.form.submit();'}))
```

view:

```
def browse(request):
    thing_list = Thing.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = StuffBrowseForm(request.POST)
        form2 = ThingBrowseForm(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid():
            stuff = form1.cleaned_data['stuff']
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('browse_stuffs', kwargs={'stuff':stuff}))
        elif form2.is_valid():
            thing = form2.cleaned_data['thing']
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('browse_things', kwargs={'thing':thing}))
    else:
        form1 = StuffBrowseForm()
        form2 = ThingBrowseForm()
    return render(request, 'browse.html', {'form1':form1, 'form2':form2, 'thing_list':thing_list})
```

urls:

```
url(r'^browse/$', 'views.browse', name='browse'),
url(r'^browse/stuff/(?P<stuff>[\w-]+)/$', 'views.browse_stuffs', name='browse_stuffs'),
url(r'^browse/things/(?P<thing>[\w-]+)/$', 'views.browse_things', name='browse_things'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could optionally show various elements based upon whether `thing` or `stuff` was passed in, so your view would have:

```
def browse(request, thing=None, stuff=None):
    # your code, then...
    return render(request, 'browse.html', {
        'form': form,
        'thing_list': thing_list,
        'stuff_list': stuff_list,
        'has_thing': bool(thing),
        'has_stuff': bool(stuff)
    })
```

Then in your template you can do something like:

```
{% for f in form %}
    {% if f.name == 'thing' and has_thing %}
        <!-- render it -->
    {% endif %}
    {% if f.name == 'stuff' and has_stuff %}
        <!-- render it -->
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also remember to set `required=False` in your `BrowseForm` fields so you don't get validation errors on `POST` since you'll only have one or the other.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think you may have misunderstood what I am trying to accomplish. Rather than displaying one form based on either `stuff` or `thing`, I want to have multiple forms and re-direct to the appropriate url based on whether the user has  submitted `stuff` **OR** `thing`. Any ideas for me? Thanks!